# How to send key a date with format of MM/YY using python selenium

Tags: python, selenium

Im trying to fill the expiry date of credit card using this code

driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='authnet-card-expiry']").send_keys('0122')

however its not displaying my expected result

4[image]

here's the element

[image]

Comment: If you use the site as human, does it require you to enter the slash "/"?

Comment: no its automatically formatted

Comment: pls update question with url or web elements without posting image of element

Comment: I update my post now.

Comment: can you update url of site ?

Answer (score 2):

Give a time gap about 1sec between month and year.

Firstly give the number of month and then time sleep during 1sec. Finally send the number of year.

like as below.

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('"input path"').send_keys("month")
time.sleep(1)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('"input path"').send_keys("year")
```

Comment: After you try this method, you can modify gap time under 1sec.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there's not feature in selenium to slow down input while send_keys function, but fortunately, python is quite strong for everything.

Here's solution. but it's seems like there's already good one above:

```
el = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='authnet-card-expiry']")

def type_text(element, text, timeout=0.3):
    import time
    element.clear()
    for s in text:
        time.sleep(timeout)
        element.send_keys(s)


type_text(el, "0122")
```

Comment: @JHN it’s quite convenient to change timeout, even help with usual inputs, the data might be missed as well

Comment: hey @vova sorry to bother you again but I need to ask for a help again  :D  here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67120121/i-tried-to-update-all-the-existing-value-under-my-profile-but-its-not-working