# I tried to update all the existing value under my profile but its not working - Python selenium

Tags: python, selenium

So I wanted to update all the existing value under my profile and during the execution I can see that the new value is being entered in the text field however as soon as my script execute the click save button it gets back to its previous value. I'm confused can someone help me on this :) please..

thank you

This is my script

```
driver.find_element_by_link_text('SIGN IN').click()
time.sleep(1)


#enter credentials
welcome = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//h1[contains(text(),'Welcome back!')]")
user_email = driver.find_element_by_name('email').send_keys("")
user_pass = driver.find_element_by_name('password').send_keys("")
driver.find_element_by_link_text('SIGN IN').click()

print(welcome.text)
print(driver.title)
print("sign in passed")


wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 5)
profile_id = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//header/div[1]/div[1]/img[1]")))
profile_id.click()
time.sleep(3)
prof_ele = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Edit Profile')]")
log_out = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[contains(text(),'Logout')]")
print(prof_ele.text)
print(log_out.text)
prof_ele.click()


#edit profile
#Name
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//body/div[@id='root']/div[2]/div[2]/form[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/*[1]").click()
name_ele = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//body/div[@id='root']/div[2]/div[2]/form[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/input[1]")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].value=arguments[1]", name_ele, "My name is John")

# Occupation
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//body/div[@id='root']/div[2]/div[2]/form[1]/div[2]/div[4]/div[1]/div[1]/*[1]").click()
occupation_ele = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//body/div[@id='root']/div[2]/div[2]/form[1]/div[2]/div[4]/div[1]/div[1]/input[1]")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].value=arguments[1]", occupation_ele, "QA analyst")

#about me
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//body/div[@id='root']/div[2]/div[2]/form[1]/div[2]/div[4]/div[2]/div[1]/*[1]").click()
bio_ele = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//body/div[@id='root']/div[2]/div[2]/form[1]/div[2]/div[4]/div[2]/div[1]/input[1]")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].value=arguments[1]", bio_ele, "Nothing to say about me")

#birthday
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//body/div[@id='root']/div[2]/div[2]/form[1]/div[2]/div[4]/div[3]/div[1]/*[1]").click()
birthday = driver.find_element_by_name("birthday")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].value=arguments[1]", birthday, "1993-06-20")

#web
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//body/div[@id='root']/div[2]/div[2]/form[1]/div[2]/div[4]/div[4]/div[1]/*[1]").click()
web_ele = driver.find_element_by_name("website")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].value=arguments[1]", web_ele, "www.instagram.com")

#hobbies
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//body/div[@id='root']/div[2]/div[2]/form[1]/div[2]/div[4]/div[5]/div[1]/*[1]").click()
hobbies = driver.find_element_by_name("interests")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].value=arguments[1]", hobbies, "Run, Eat, Photography")

time.sleep(3)

driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[contains(text(),'Save')]").click()

alert = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.alert_is_present())
print(alert.text)
alert.accept()

time.sleep(5)


print(name_ele.get_attribute('value'))
print(occupation_ele.get_attribute('value'))
print(bio_ele.get_attribute('value'))
print(birthday.get_attribute('value'))
print(hobbies.get_attribute('value'))

print("All tests passed!")
```

Comment: Is there link to the page?

Comment: Try to avoid email sharing

Comment: https://webapp.bailiwik.com/

Comment: actually its just a test email :D but I deleted the screenshots and in script :D

Answer (score 1):

I have update for 1 of the fields, try to check it out:

```
import time

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get('you_site')

driver.find_element_by_link_text('SIGN IN').click()
time.sleep(1)

# enter credentials
welcome = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//h1[contains(text(),'Welcome back!')]")
user_email = driver.find_element_by_name('email').send_keys("email")
user_pass = driver.find_element_by_name('password').send_keys("password")
driver.find_element_by_link_text('SIGN IN').click()

print(welcome.text)
print(driver.title)
print("sign in passed")

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 5)
profile_id = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//header/div[1]/div[1]/img[1]")))
profile_id.click()
time.sleep(3)
prof_ele = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Edit Profile')]")
log_out = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[contains(text(),'Logout')]")
print(prof_ele.text)
print(log_out.text)
prof_ele.click()

# Name
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='name']/following-sibling::*").click()
name_ele = driver.find_element_by_xpath(
    "//input[@name='name']")
name_ele.clear()
name_ele.send_keys("My name is John")

# NickName
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='display_name']/following-sibling::*").click()
name_ele = driver.find_element_by_xpath(
    "//input[@name='display_name']")
name_ele.clear()
name_ele.send_keys("My name is NickName")
```

I would suggest using XPATH engine and read a bit about it, it really powerful and trying avoid entirely obsolute selectors, like:

```
//body/div[@id='root']/div[2]/div[2]/form[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/*[1]
```

and replace on dynamic ones, like:

```
//input[@name='name']/following-sibling::*
```

Comment: looks good, but when i tried to create for nickname textfield the input is in name instead of nickname .. @vova i post the pic below

Comment: @JHN you should clear the field first, I have added

Comment: i actually did that but still the value that should be entered in nickname textfield is still going in name textfield. will post the screenshots

Comment: @JHN weird, just double check with # edit profile
# Name
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='name']/following-sibling::node()").click()
name_ele = driver.find_element_by_xpath(
    "//input[@name='name']")
name_ele.clear()
name_ele.send_keys("My name is John")
 all works fine for me

Comment: oh yeah  i didnt notice that im sending it name_ele instead of nickname.. appreciate your help :) @vova big thanks to you

Comment: @JHN did it help?you know what to do, upvote, confirm ;)))

Comment: hey @vova can i consult to you ?  how can I send you dm